# C# - Consuming a SOAP web service with certificate authentication and digital signature with BinarySecurityToken

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

It's my first time dealing with SOAP web services so I don't know very well to solve the next problem. I tried to link the certificate to the SOAP client, but when I call the web service an error with 500 code is thrown.

I sniffed the packages with Wireshark to know the XML that is being sent to the web service, and I get a soap envelope correctly formed, but with no header and, therefore, no signature, reason why the server is rejecting my requests.

I also tested the web service in SoapUI with an outgoing WS-Security configuration with the certificate and it worked perfectly, so it's clearly problem of my code.

This is my code right now:

```
VTCPortClient cliente = new VTCPortClient("VTCPortImplPort");

//Information sent to the service
qconsultavtc qConsultaVTC = new qconsultavtc();
HEADERTYPE header = new HEADERTYPE();
CBODYTYPE body = new CBODYTYPE();
qConsultaVTC.header = header;
qConsultaVTC.body = body;
DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
qConsultaVTC.header.fecha = fecha;
qConsultaVTC.header.version = "1.0";
qConsultaVTC.header.versionsender = "1.0";
EVTCCONSULTA vtcconsulta = new EVTCCONSULTA();
qConsultaVTC.body.vtcconsulta = vtcconsulta;
qConsultaVTC.body.vtcconsulta.idservicio = 1;

//Setting the certificate for the client
cliente.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, "4ede26f5675d15545a02d13d75aaa84e");   


cliente.ChannelFactory.Open();
//Calling the web service through its method ConsultaDeServicio
rconsultavtc respuesta = cliente.ConsultaDeServicio(qConsultaVTC);
cliente.ChannelFactory.Close();
```

I would like to know why my certificate is not being linked correctly and how to properly set up in my code the configuration that works when I test the service with SoapUI.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Did you start your asmx? Else you won't be able to access to the file as it does'nt exist. Try this : right click on your asmx, open in browser and then try to consume your web service. I suggest you to use SoapUI to test your web services

Comment: I didn't devolope the web service, I only have to consume it

Comment: Then add the web service reference in your project (right click on reference, add new service reference, advanced, advanced, put the path of the service and name it, then add). Then you will be able to call the service

Comment: I've added the service reference, the problem is with the signature when I try to call it

Comment: I guess you have followed this tutorial : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/901183/how-to-call-a-web-service-by-using-a-client-certificate-for-authentica

Answer (score 0):

How do you generate the client proxy class? what is the error details? Generally, when we authenticate the client with a certificate, we should establish the trust relationship between the server and the client.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
When we use message security mode, we need to set the default service certificate, like below.

```
    //message security, we need to sepcify both the default certificate and the client certificate.

    ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
 client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");
    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9b8db0dfe615458ace0ae9e89fcb983c5d16f633");
        var result = client.SayHello();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The default service certificate is the certificate on the server-side, which could encrypt the SOAP message by using its public key on the client-side.
Besides, we had better use Local Machine certificate store location in case that some permissions issues.
Please carefully check the serial number of the certificate. It looks like there is an extra number. We generally use the thumbprint of the certificate to set up the certificate.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.